# C++ bounding box triangle collision

Tags: c++, geometry, collision-detection, bounding-box

I need an algorithm for know if a bounding box axis align (like a cube but the sides are not equal) and a triangle intersect in a 3D space.

I am doing the code in C++, if the solution is extremly long, better in C++ (if you can) :), if it is a few lines don't worry if it is another language.

(Determine if a vertex of the triangle is inside the box is easy, but is not easy determine if  if the box and the triangle intersects but all vertex are outside of the box and the triangle.)

(An algorithm of an intersection between a rectangle and a triangle in a 3d space is good too, I can divide the bounding box in 6 planes)

Comment: Have you tried a websearch? I got a **bunch** of results there...

Comment: There are generally two approaches. You can use per-pixel detection. If the pixels of two object overlaps, they collides, no collision else. If you are good at math, you can implement SAT algorithm: http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html

Comment: "Have you tried a websearch? I got a bunch of results there"
Yes, and results are a disaster.
It is possible do a Pixel detection in 3D?

Comment: A triangle lies in a plane. Intersect the plane with the box. If there is no intersection, great. If there is, you get back a convex polygon (up to 6 sides). Now intersect it with the triangle (which is also a convex polygon). To sum up, you need (1) box/plane intersection (2) convex polygon intersection (3) a way to go from 3D coordinates in space to 2D coordinates in the plane, and back. All three are easy and easily googlable.