# How to test if Triangle intersects Box3?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I need to check whether a `THREE.Triangle` overlaps with a `THREE.Box3` object. Is there an existing function in `THREE.js` for this purpose? If not, how could I achieve this?

Comment: For your first question, the answer is no, there is no single existing function to do this. You may be able to use combinations of other functions to accomplish your goal, but that brushes your second question. For that, we'll need more info, like what have you tried so far, and maybe some example code showing how what you have tried doesn't work.

Comment: After a quick search, I also found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919878/c-bounding-box-triangle-collision

Comment: @TheJim01 Thanks for your reply. I already searched for the topic of Cube-Triangle intersection and found some approaches (e.g. SAT). I was just wondering if there would be an easier/faster THREE.js-built-in solution apart from implementing such an algorithm such as SAT by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no in-built function for a triangle-box-intersection test I came up implementing such an algorithm by myself. It is based on Separating-Axis-Theorem (SAT) as suggested by TheJim01. For my use case I needed a test for an axis aligned bounding box (AABB).

The following sources were especially helpful for this.

[AABB Triangle intersection](https://gdbooks.gitbooks.io/3dcollisions/content/Chapter4/aabb-triangle.html)

[Fast 3D Triangle-Box Overlap Testing (Akenine-Möller)](http://fileadmin.cs.lth.se/cs/personal/tomas_akenine-moller/code/tribox_tam.pdf)

The book "Real-Time Collision Detection (Christer Ericson), pp. 169-172 (found online Google Book)

Using these sources, it wasn't that hard to implement this test. However, during my research I figured out that such an AABB-Triangle test is a quite common operation in 3D graphics. Hence, I guess it would make sense having such a testing function in `THREE.js`. I will suggest this as a feature request.

Comment: Your second link is dead, unfortunately.  Can you remove or edit it please?